# How to make regex for name abbreviation

Tags: php, regex

I have original data like this

**Original Data:**

- SRI ISTYANINGSIH
- DIANA WREDHININGSIH
- ENDANG WAHYU PURWANINGSIH
- THERESIA PUDJI ASTUTIE SARI

And I need to show it like this:

**View Data:**

- SRI I.
- DIANA W.
- ENDANG W. P.
- THERESIA P. A. S.

How can I accomplish this using PHP and regular expressions?

Comment: do you want to do it with regex only? If you want to do with PHP then checkout my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple solution which could easily be turned into a function.

```
$name = 'THERESIA PUDJI ASTUTIE SARI';

//split the name to a maximum of 2 array values.
list ($first_name, $second_names) = explode(' ', $name, 2);

$second_names = explode(' ', $second_names);

foreach ($second_names as $key => $value) {
    $second_names[$key] = $value[0] . '.';
}

echo $first_name . ' ' . implode(' ', $second_names);
```

Answer (score 1):

suppose, $var has the string that you want to convert.

```
$var = "THERESIA PUDJI ASTUTIE SARI";

$parts = explode(" ", $var);
$str = $parts[0]." ";
for($i=1; $i<count($parts); $i++){
    $str .= $parts[$i][0].". ";
}

echo $str will give you desired output.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean with "make delimiter" but here is a regular expression based solution:

```
function shorten_name($name) {
    return preg_replace('/ (\w)\w*/', ' $1.', $name);
}
```

The pattern matches a space followed by any number of "word characters" (`\w`), i.e. letters (locale aware), digits and underscores, then replaces this sequence with only the space, the first letter and a dot.

**Possible modifications:**

- If you only want to match uppercase letters from A-Z like in your example, replace `\w` with `[A-Z]`.
- If you want to match anything that is not a space (i.e. "MÜLLER-RIEBENSEE" => "M."), replace `\w` with `\S` (non-whitespace).
- If you want to have other characters than the space as separator, use character class and subpattern for it too for example: `preg_replace('/([\s-])(\w)\w*/', '$1$2.', $name)` to take any whitespace character `\s` or the dash `-` as separator (i.e. "MÜLLER-RIEBENSEE" => "M.-R.")

Comment: I suggested some variations regarding probable special cases, see updated answer.